# Unable to step through foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net

```
private async void Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder s;
    s = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> l = await s.GetFilesAsync();
    bool exists=false;
    foreach (StorageFile sf in l)
    {
        if (string.Equals(sf.Name, "encrypted.txt", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            exists = true;
    }
    MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog(exists.ToString());
    await d.ShowAsync();
}
```

When debugging the code, I'm not able to step through the code inside the `foreach` loop

While the value of exists at the end of the loop is correct, and I can see the loop execution if I put the `MessageDialog` code inside the loop, any idea how to step into the loop properly?

Even when I put the `MessageDialog` code in the loop, I'm unable to step into the if condition, so I suspect the issue lies somewhere in there

**EDIT**: Putting a breakpoint on the if condition works (currently I'm putting it on the 1st line of the function), but shouldn't I be able to step into the loop normally using F11 if I'm debugging line by line anyways? (atleast that's how it worked in TurboC)

**EDIT2**: Easiest way I could think of to show the issue clearly: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10GgXCqLlVo&feature=youtu.be (skip to 25 second mark to see the actual issue)

Comment: are you in a debug build? a release build?

Comment: @MarcGravell its a debug build, also added more details

Comment: F11 steps *into* a member usually - F10 is step *over* the current statement.

Comment: What if you simply put break point *inside* foreach? Will be' it hitted?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, so F11 should step into the for loop, then into the if condition, right? or am I misinterpreting the meanings of over and into?

Comment: @Akash: No, a loop isn't a member. I mean that if you use F11, you would end up going into the code for `string.Equals` if you have it available. If you want to just keep going in the current method, you use F10. I don't think that's the actual problem here, but it's worth being clear about it.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, ok. Yeah, had a rough idea about that, but usually it didn't step into library functions for me anyways with F11 either so used F11 only

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of how debugging works with async methods (I don't tend to use debuggers much), but you need to understand that the system will basically call back into the method, having returned from it (as far as the caller is concerned) when it first reaches an `await` expression which hasn't already completed.

I would put a break point on the `bool exists=false;` line, i.e. *after* the first `await` expression. You should then be able to use F10 (step over) to iterate through the loop.

Alternatively, you could get rid of the loop entirely using LINQ:

```
bool exists = l.Any(sf => string.Equals(sf.Name, "encrypted.txt",
                              StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Putting the breakpoint on the `bool exists=false` statement has the same result :(  Will probably use the LINQ method though, seems more appropriate for this case.

Comment: @Akash: It's not clear what you mean by "the same result" - what happens *exactly*?

Comment: The debugger still doesn't enter the `foreach` loop (It just highlights `l` in the `foreach` line once and jumps to the `MessageDialog` line

Comment: If it helps, made a short video recording of it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10GgXCqLlVo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Akash: Okay, that does look very odd. No idea at this point, I'm afraid. If you can post a short but complete program as a zip file, I could try it at home tonight...

Comment: I've uploaded it to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/75629414/App3.zip .You just need to launch and click on the Button. If you have a file named "Encrypted.txt" in your documents folder, the popup will show true, else it will show false

Comment: @Akash: Just tried it, and I was able to step over (with F10) with no problems. It threw an exception on the last line, mind you.